# Using XAML resource to reduce repetition

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a scenario where I'm passing in the same values to a multivalue converter for different buttons within a data template which all works fine. But was wondering way to make the code better by removing the repeatable elements, since I'm passing in the same content into

```
<telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="ViewCommentsDialog">
        <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
        <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
        <Binding Path="Comment"/>
        <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
```

Code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <telerik:RadButton Margin="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewCommentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="ViewCommentsDialog">
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="Comment"/>
                    <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Mizuho.Minar.UI.Common;component/png/Comments.png" />
            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Margin="2" Command="{Binding  DataContext.AddCommentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="AddCommentDialog">
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="Comment"/>
                    <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Mizuho.Minar.UI.Common;component/png/Comment-Add.png" />
            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Margin="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewBreaksCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="ViewBreaksDialog">
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                    <Binding Path="Comment"/>
                    <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Mizuho.Minar.UI.Common;component/png/Folder-Bug.png" />
            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
        </telerik:RadButton>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two quite simple approaches to this.

#### Option 1 - bind to other property.

You can set your binding (multibinding actually) on some other dependency property, and then bind your buttons visibility to that property. If you don't have any good candidate for such property, you can use some simple object with single dependency property placed in the Resources collection. Here is the code of the class for such object:

```
public class VisibilityValueHolder : ValueHolder<Visibility> { }

public abstract class ValueHolder<T> : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(T), typeof(ValueHolder<T>), null);
    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public ValueHolder() { }

    public ValueHolder(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And the usage in your code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <common:VisibilityValueHolder x:Key="VisibilityHolder">
                <common:VisibilityValueHolder.Value>
                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="ViewCommentsDialog">
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                        <Binding Path="Comment"/>
                        <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </common:VisibilityValueHolder.Value>
            </common:VisibilityValueHolder.Value>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <telerik:RadButton Margin="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewCommentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Visibility={Binding Value, Source={StaticResource VisibilityHolder}}>
            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Mizuho.Minar.UI.Common;component/png/Comments.png" />
            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
        </telerik:RadButton>
```

#### Option 2 - use Style with binding in the Setter

You can either declare implicit or explicit style (in case when you want to apply the same visibility to all your buttons, or just to the selected ones).

Your code would look like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
                <Setter Property="Visibility">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueToBooleanConverter}" ConverterParameter="ViewCommentsDialog">
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CanEdit" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CanView" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                            <Binding Path="Comment"/>
                            <Binding Path="ExecutionId"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <telerik:RadButton Margin="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewCommentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Mizuho.Minar.UI.Common;component/png/Comments.png" />
            </telerik:RadButton.Content>
        </telerik:RadButton>
```